# unable to test webhook by sending cURL request

Tags: javascript, facebook, curl, webhooks, facebook-webhooks

I am trying to test my webhook by sending this cURL request:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST "localhost:1337/webhook" -d '{"object": "page", "entry": [{"messaging": [{"message": "TEST_MESSAGE"}]}]}'
```

I am follwing this guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/getting-started/webhook-setup/

when i run the cURL request i get this error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>SyntaxError: Unexpected token &#39; in JSON at position 0<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at JSON.parse (&lt;anonymous&gt;)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at createStrictSyntaxError (C:\Users\vveen\messenger-webhook\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:158:10)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at parse (C:\Users\vveen\messenger-webhook\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users\vveen\messenger-webhook\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at invokeCallback (C:\Users\vveen\messenger-webhook\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at done (C:\Users\vveen\messenger-webhook\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\vveen\messenger-webhook\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:228:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1185:12)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)</pre>
</body>
</html>
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: page,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: entry
curl: (3) [globbing] bad range specification in column 2
curl: (3) [globbing] bad range specification in column 2
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 13
```

The  file code:

```
'use strict';

// Imports dependencies and set up http server
const
  express = require('express'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  app = express().use(bodyParser.json()); // creates express http server

// Sets server port and logs message on success
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 1337, () => console.log('webhook is listening'));


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Creates the endpoint for our webhook 
app.post('/webhook', (req, res) => {  

  let body = req.body;

  // Checks this is an event from a page subscription
  if (body.object === 'page') {

    // Iterates over each entry - there may be multiple if batched
    body.entry.forEach(function(entry) {

      // Gets the message. entry.messaging is an array, but 
      // will only ever contain one message, so we get index 0
      let webhook_event = entry.messaging[0];
      console.log(webhook_event);
    });

    // Returns a '200 OK' response to all requests
    res.status(200).send('EVENT_RECEIVED');
  } else {
    // Returns a '404 Not Found' if event is not from a page subscription
    res.sendStatus(404);
  }

});

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Adds support for GET requests to our webhook
app.get('/webhook', (req, res) => {

  // Your verify token. Should be a random string.
  let VERIFY_TOKEN = "<qwertyuiop>"

  // Parse the query params
  let mode = req.query['hub.mode'];
  let token = req.query['hub.verify_token'];
  let challenge = req.query['hub.challenge'];

  // Checks if a token and mode is in the query string of the request
  if (mode && token) {

    // Checks the mode and token sent is correct
    if (mode === 'subscribe' && token === VERIFY_TOKEN) {

      // Responds with the challenge token from the request
      console.log('WEBHOOK_VERIFIED');
      res.status(200).send(challenge);

    } else {
      // Responds with '403 Forbidden' if verify tokens do not match
      res.sendStatus(403);      
    }
  }
});
```

I have looked for answers elsewhere on the web but nothing resolves it.

Comment: Can you please share your code which serves this url `localhost:1337/webhook` ?

Comment: @EhsanT - I added the code to the question

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too, but it worked when I tested using Postman instead of cURL. My guess is that cURL can't parse so many brackets.

Comment: Thanks @kodaima. When I try that I get a not found response.

Comment: Have you tried putting the JSON into a temporary file and calling Curl with ```-d @filename.json```? That way Curl would not have to parse brackets.